# Open a powerpoint presentation and hide the window

Tags: c#, .net, vsto, powerpoint, powerpoint-2010

I am trying to open a PowerPoint presentation, and have it hidden. I am doing it this way:

```
app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Application();
string presentation = "C:\\presentation.pptx";

Presentation p = app.Presentations.Open(presentation, MsoTriState.msoFalse, MsoTriState.msoFalse, MsoTriState.msoFalse);
```

It is the simplest thing, yet I receive an error saying:

> Application (unknown member) : Invalid request. There is no active
>   presentation.

However, if I switch the last parameter (which is the WithWindow parameter) to **MsoTriState.msoTrue**, the presentation opens fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have any other add-ins that might be causing that error?
I ran your code (from VBA) and it ran fine.

Comment: Hmmm...Good point... I actually have a Powerpoint add-in that tries to modify the Powerpoint as soon as it is loaded. So definitely that might be causing the problem (as per this [answer](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/285472))...Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The code provided in the question works correctly, but there is an important note:

In C# you have to leave `Application.Visible` property with it's default value:

```
var application = new Application();
var document = application.Presentations.Open(fileName, MsoTriState.msoFalse, MsoTriState.msoFalse, 
    WithWindow: MsoTriState.msoFalse);
```

If you explicitly set `Application.Visible` property to `MsoTriState.msoFalse` you will get "Hiding the application window is not allowed" error.

Comment: This is a one difference for Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint library compared with word or excel - word and excel allow you to app visibility to false. PowerPoint App will throw the error specified by @opewix

Answer (score 0):

I've tried this one, and it works:

```
Presentation p = app.Presentations.Open(presentation,0, 0, 0);
```